# SQLite issues even with example apps

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been having issues getting my SQLite Databases to work and I think it might be something other than my code. I downloaded a sample SQLite app from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android) and it doesn't work on my emulator or my phone.  Here are the LogCat errors for you to look at.

If you have any ideas on what might be going on please let me know.

```
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653): Error inserting DeptID=3 DeptName=HR
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1582)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at mina.android.DatabaseDemo.DatabaseHelper.InsertDepts(DatabaseHelper.java:144)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at mina.android.DatabaseDemo.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:65)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:126)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at mina.android.DatabaseDemo.DatabaseHelper.getEmployeeCount(DatabaseHelper.java:105)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at mina.android.DatabaseDemo.AddEmployee.onStart(AddEmployee.java:40)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1624)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1491)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:657)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:329)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:219)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at mina.android.DatabaseDemo.DatabaseDemo.SetupTabs(DatabaseDemo.java:85)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at mina.android.DatabaseDemo.DatabaseDemo.onCreate(DatabaseDemo.java:32)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3688)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-04 00:48:26.472: E/Database(6653):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 00:48:26.925: W/PhoneWindow(6653): Previously focused view reported id 2131034112 during save, but can't be found during restore.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in this example. Look at `DatabaseHelper:144`. You'll find this line of code twice:

```
db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);
```

The first call succeeds, the second is trying to insert a row with the same ID, so it violates the primary key constraint. Delete it.

I don't understand why someone is publishing untested code examples...